# Solve ODE $\frac{d^2v(x)}{dx}+\lambda v(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve ODE $$\begin{cases}
\frac{d^2v(x)}{dx}+\lambda v(x)=0, 0<x<L\\
v'(0)=v'(L)=0, 0\leq x\leq L\\
\end{cases}$$

So we look at 3 cases: 1. $\lambda =0$ 2. $\lambda >0$ 3. $\lambda <0$

for case 1: I got
$$v(x)=const$$

for case 2:
$$v(x)=c_1 \cos(\frac{\pi n}{L}x)$$

for case 3:
I got to:

$$v(x)=c_1e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}$$

using the boundary condition $v'(0)=0$ I got: $c_1=c_2$

But in the solution I got they look at a determinant of a matrix, I think it is the Jacobean matrix, why is that?

$$\begin{cases}
c_1+c_2=0\\
c_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}L}-c_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}L}\\
\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{vmatrix} 
1 & -1 \\
e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}L} & -e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}L} 
\end{vmatrix}=-e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}L}+e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}L}\neq 0$$

Comment: What was the matrix? Please show it. The Jacobian that I’m familiar with from multi variable calculus wouldn’t make much sense here, since you’re dealing with a single variable.

Comment: @Joe I have added the matrix to the qeustion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix encodes the two linear conditions on $c_1$ and $c_2$. The determinant not vanishing means there *are* some constants satisfying both conditions, as the matrix is invertible. Which gives you a systematic way of calculating the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$. Of course you can also just make an educated guess and verify it is correct.

You should also check the signs in your third solution. With $\lambda < 0$ and your current signs you'd wind up with another oscillatory solution to the ODE. Whereas the entries in the matrix from the solution are honest real exponentials for $\lambda < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your case $1$ and case $2$ are good. For case $3$, I'd let $p^2=-\lambda$, so we have that
$$v''=p^2v$$
So the solution will have the form
$$v(x)=A\sinh(px)+B\cosh(px)$$
And from this, $v'(0)=0 \implies A=0$ and $v'(L)=Bp\sinh(pL)=0 \implies B=0$ (using the assumption $\lambda\neq 0$ and $L\neq 0$).